# Change keyboard shortcut for switching applications in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as the shortcut to switch applications in Mac OS X, instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there any way to switch the keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: Any solutions WITHOUT remapping of keys? I don't want to remap option to command. I just want to change the freaking shortcut!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find any solution without remapping..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, there are many ways.

The easiest for what you are doing would be to use the open-source program **[DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/)**.

Here is a view of the interface:

[image]

---

As you can see it is extremely customizable.  If that doens't fulfill your needs, there is also **[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)** (formerly known as **KeyRemap4MacBook**).

---

There is also a shareware program called **[LiteSwitchX](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8242/liteswitch-x)** that completely replaces the switcher with an even cooler and more customizable one that I will eventually get around to installing.

I hope this helps.

---

You can also use a combination of two programs: **Application Enhancer** (by Unsanity, free) and **PullTab** (open source and free).  PullTab ONLY removes the shortcut from use so it depends on exactly what you're looking for.  Application Enhancer (APE as it's commonly called) also has WindowShadeX and MenuMaster, which I recommend at least checking out.

I'm going to continue looking for a non-third party way to disable this, I may edit it again.

---

## BONUS

Also, press cmd+` (command + backtick: backtick is directly under Escape, with the tilde) to cycle through the current application's windows rather than cycling through each application.

### One more thing:

When you are in the application switcher, you can also press Q and/or H and the currently selected application will be quitted or hidden.

Comment: I'm so sad, I had hoped at least someone would upvote me.  I'm going back to SO to practice my markdown.  :)

Comment: I have bad experience with DoubleCommand - it is very confusing, the moment it applies settings is unclear. Eventually it has blocked all my input and I had to reboot in order to be able to type.

Answer (score 3):

**Windows alt-tab on macOS**

https://alt-tab-macos.netlify.app/

This app allows you to configure your alt-tab experience without having to remap your keys. You can simply define they key combination (and many more useful things). It is a game changer on macOS for me.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do this. Besides, Ctrl-Tab is already used in some applications, like Safari, to e.g. switch between tabs.

You can use [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) for a custom application switcher and use `Ctrl-Tab` for that.

In *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard » Modifier Keys*, you can switch positions of the keys. This will however change all keyboard shortcuts (e.g. `Cmd-C` for *copy* effectively becomes `Ctrl-C`).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_CONTROL | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::TAB, VK_CONTROL | VK_SHIFT | ModifierFlag::NONE, , KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/Cocoa%20Text%20System.html has some great info about changing the default key bindings for Cocoa applications. Unfortunately I could not figure out if there is an action method for the switcher.

Answer (score -2):

Command + Tab in Mac similiar to Command + Tab in windows
You can use KeyRemap4Macbook for activation this change:

Command + Tab to Command + Tab + Alt

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>

Your life more easy :)

Comment: Is this explaining the same thing Lri did? (But in a much worse way)