# Change Command-Shift-Tab on OSX

Tags: macos

How can i change the combination Command-Shift-Tab on OSX or get the same result by setting another combination - so to switch between the history stack?

Comment: Not totally clear what you want. Assign a different key (which?) to moving backwards through the open applications?

Comment: The key combination i want to assign doesnt matter, i want to find a the way to assign it, as it is not available through settings

Comment: Which key combination is relevant because there are some [third-party solutions](http://superuser.com/q/223893/226698) which can change the setting, but they seem to have limited options.

Comment: Alt+Space  would do:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but it sounds similar to this question: [Change keyboard shortcut for switching applications in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/223893/change-keyboard-shortcut-for-switching-applications-in-os-x?lq=1)

It sounds like you want [KeyRemap4Macbook](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), which is now called Karabiner. It has an option called Tabmode that lets you set the shortcut for switching applications.

> What's Tabmode?
>   It replaces the default shortcut for switching applications. (cmd+tab)
>   While tab is pressed, use your favorite combination of left/right keys to switch between apps.
>   It has evolved into a window manager shortcut, capable of managing windows, tabs,
>   spaces and split views.

It has options to change both Command-Tab and Command-Shift-Tab. If you only want to change Command-Shift-Tab you will have to create the option yourself in the private.xml. Conveniently you can edit this file by clicking the `Open private.xml` in the `Musc & Uninstall` tab in Karabiner.

To see examples of how to write it go to `/Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Resources` and if you go to `include/checkbox/standards/tab.xml` inside of `/Resources` you will find how the Tabmode is written for Karabiner on line 216. However, it is much easier to just use the defaults which have most of what you could want.

Comment: This is a good recommendation. I would love to see a means of application switching that doesnt involve using the weak side of the hand (tab key, command key etc). That is to say, a home-row only application switch, or somethign that uses index fingers and extended thumbs. Karabiner does not seem to allow one to bind a key different key to send tab, and then use tabmode with that key.